# Electron: How to reference global BrowserWindow object in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to reference the global `window` variable (containing the Electron BrowserWindow object) in another file that I'm including with require(). But it's not working and I'm not sure why.

In my main.js file I have, roughly:

```
const { BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron')
const menuTemplate = require('./menu')

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)

let window

function createWindow() {
    window = new BrowserWindow(...)
    window.show()
}
```

Then, in my menu.js file:

```
const template = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Log out',
                click() {
                    window.webContents.on(...)
                }
            }
        ]
    }

module.exports = template
```

But when I try and execute the "Log out" function (by clicking on that menu item), I get an error about `window` not being defined.

Since `window` is already defined as a global variable, why is it undefined in the other file? I've tried doing various things like injecting it and exporting it etc. but it's always undefined. I'm not sure what's wrong here and would love some help.

Comment: Try `const template = function(window) { return { ... }; };` and `const menuTemplate = require('./menu')(window);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to export a function that returns the template

```
module.exports = window => { 
    const template = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Log out',
                    click() {
                        window.webContents.on(...)
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
   return template;
};
```

from the `main.js` file you will require the `menu.js` module like this

```
const menuTemplate = require('./menu')

function createwindow() {
   window = new BrowserWindow(...)
   window.show()
   menuTemplate(window)        
}
```

Comment: Well, I thought this would work, but the nothing gets returned by `menuTemplate(window)`

Comment: Well, I just saw you updated your answer as I was typing this comment. I didn't know that when using `{ }` with the arrow function, there is no implied return. Adding that fixed the problem (alternatively, from your solution, just replace "const" with "return" rather than the extra line at the bottom). Thanks!